# Elasticsearch 2.2 does not take "boost" into account

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with elastic search 2.2:

I have the following search query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "indices": {
      "index": "my_index",
      "query": {
        "dis_max": {
          "tie_breaker": 0,
          "boost": 2,
          "queries": [
            {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                      "searchName"
                    ],
                    "query": "\"sala\"",
                    "use_dis_max": false,
                    "boost": 10
                  }
                },
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "rank",
                  "factor": 11,
                  "modifier": "log1p"
                },
                "boost_mode": "sum",
                "boost": 20
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "no_match_query": "none"
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

Running the query on Elasticsearch 2.1, "explain" returns the following result:

```
{
   "took":16,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":21,
      "successful":21,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":19,
      "max_score":227.97464,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_source":{
               "rank":0,
               "searchName":"Puma evoSPEED Sala 3.4"
            },
            "_explanation":{
               "value":227.97464,
               "description":"function score, product of:",
               "details":[
                  {
                     "value":5.699366,
                     "description":"sum of",
                     "details":[
                        {
                           "value":5.699366,
                           "description":"weight(searchName:sala^10.0 in 29236) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                           "details":[
                              {
                                 "value":5.699366,
                                 "description":"fieldWeight in 29236, product of:",
                                 "details":[
                                    {
                                       "value":1,
                                       "description":"tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                       "details":[
                                          {
                                             "value":1,
                                             "description":"termFreq=1.0",
                                             "details":[

                                             ]
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value":11.398732,
                                       "description":"idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=131272)",
                                       "details":[

                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "value":0.5,
                                       "description":"fieldNorm(doc=29236)",
                                       "details":[

                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "value":0,
                           "description":"min of:",
                           "details":[
                              {
                                 "value":0,
                                 "description":"field value function: log1p(doc['rank'].value * factor=11.0)",
                                 "details":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              {
                                 "value":3.4028235e+38,
                                 "description":"maxBoost",
                                 "details":[

                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "value":40,
                     "description":"queryBoost",
                     "details":[

                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

On Elasticsearch 2.2, however, "explain" returns the following result:

```
{
   "took":15,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":21,
      "successful":21,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":19,
      "max_score":5.743438,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_source":{
               "rank":0,
               "searchName":"Puma evoSPEED Sala 3.4"
            },
            "_explanation":{
               "value":5.743438,
               "description":"sum of",
               "details":[
                  {
                     "value":5.743438,
                     "description":"weight(searchName:sala in 88079) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                     "details":[
                        {
                           "value":5.743438,
                           "description":"fieldWeight in 88079, product of:",
                           "details":[
                              {
                                 "value":1,
                                 "description":"tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                 "details":[
                                    {
                                       "value":1,
                                       "description":"termFreq=1.0",
                                       "details":[

                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              },
                              {
                                 "value":11.486876,
                                 "description":"idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=143368)",
                                 "details":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              {
                                 "value":0.5,
                                 "description":"fieldNorm(doc=88079)",
                                 "details":[

                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "value":0,
                     "description":"min of:",
                     "details":[
                        {
                           "value":0,
                           "description":"field value function: log1p(doc['rank'].value * factor=11.0)",
                           "details":[

                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "value":3.4028235e+38,
                           "description":"maxBoost",
                           "details":[

                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, the field used for the factor is 0 in both cases, but in ES2.1, the score of the document is 227.97464 (which is correct) and in ES2.2 it is 5.743438.

In ES2.1, the outermost calculation contains a "function score, product of:" of the boost (40 = 20 * 2) and the calculated score of 5.699366.

In ES2.2, this step is missing and therefore the result is just 5.743438. The small difference of 5.699366 to 5.743438 is probably ok, because there is a slightly different number of documents in the index. 
However, in ES2.2, the boost should obviously still be taken in account.

Now my question is: Am I doing something wrong (and if yes: what?) or is there really a bug in the calculation of the score in Elasticsearch 2.2?